# How to upload php project to google cloud

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I will set up Mobile application server to Google App Engine.
But I have some troubles. I tried Google Cloud Platform doc. 
Please guide me.

Comment: I think the reason people have downvoted your question is that it is too vague. "Please guide me" is a bit too broad. When it comes to Google Cloud though - I feel your pain.

Comment: I didn't downvote because my initial reaction to Google Cloud was WAAAAHHH

Answer (score 1):

(1) [have a look at the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038963/setting-up-a-website-in-google-cloud).

(2) go to [this page on the Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/download), and download **Google App Engine Launcher**.

(3) Make sure you have a [workspace on Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard) with your app set up in it.

(4) Download some of the sample apps from Google Cloud, and have a play with them. You can deploy them on localhost using Google App Engine launcher.

(5) Your app needs a file called `app.yaml` (works rather like `require.js`) which configures where all the folder and file paths are (css, js, images, etc)

I hope that helps.